# Unable to select an item from select box / write in the input field. Am I handling 'key' incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I was writing a component with the code given as follows, which after rendering looks like:

[image]

I have used antd components to render the fields. The problem that I am facing is that I am neither able to select from the select box nor write in the input field as shown below. I have a feeling that I am using React's `key` inappropriately for `mocFields` in the render method which is obtained from `getMOCField`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Icon, Select, Form, Input } from "antd";
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;
import { FormComponentProps } from "antd/lib/form/Form";

type state = {
  mocFields: JSX.Element[]
};

export class MOC extends Component<FormComponentProps, state> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mocFields: []
    };
    this.addMOCField = this.addMOCField.bind(this);
    this.removeMOCField = this.removeMOCField.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {}

  removeMOCField(key, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { mocFields } = this.state;

    mocFields.splice(key, 1);

    this.setState({
      mocFields
    });
  }

  getMOCFieldFooter() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between small">
        <div className="inline-block">
          <Button
            type="primary"
            shape="circle"
            icon="plus"
            ghost
            size="small"
            className="d-font mr-1"
            onClick={this.addMOCField}
          />
          <div
            className="text-primary pointer d-font inline-block letter-spacing-1"
            onClick={this.addMOCField}
          >
            Add another&nbsp;
          </div>
          <div className="d-font inline-block letter-spacing-1">or&nbsp;</div>
          <div className="text-primary pointer d-font inline-block letter-spacing-1">
            Create a new MOC
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getMOCField(key) {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div className="inline-block">
          <FormItem label="Select MOC">
            {getFieldDecorator(`selected_moc[${key}]`, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please select moc"
                }
              ]
            })(
              <Select>
                <Option value={"A"}>A</Option>
                <Option value={"B"}>B</Option>
              </Select>
            )}
          </FormItem>
        </div>

        <div className="inline-block">
          <FormItem label="Recovery (%)">
            {getFieldDecorator(`recovery_percentage[${key}]`, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please input the recovery percentage"
                }
              ]
            })(<Input type="number" step="0.000001" />)}
          </FormItem>
        </div>
        <div className="inline-block pointer">
          <span>
            <Icon type="close" onClick={this.removeMOCField.bind(this, key)} />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addMOCField(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { mocFields } = this.state;
    const MOCField = this.getMOCField(mocFields.length);
    mocFields.push(MOCField);

    this.setState({
      mocFields
    });
  }

  getAddMOCButton() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex w-100 mt-3">
        <Button
          type="primary"
          ghost
          className="w-100"
          onClick={this.addMOCField}
        >
          <Icon type="plus-circle" />
          Add MOC
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { mocFields } = this.state;
    const mocButton = this.getAddMOCButton();
    const toRender =
      mocFields.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="w-100 p-2 gray-background br-25">
          {mocFields.map((f, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{f}</div>
          ))}
          {this.getMOCFieldFooter()}
        </div>
      ) : (
        mocButton
      );

    return toRender;
  }
}
```

What could be the reason for this? What am I doing incorrectly? Currently the above component renders as follows:

- If the number of fields in `mocFields` is zero, then a button to add new fields is rendered.
- After the button is pressed, `mocField` is populated with the select box and input field as shown above. The key of the `div` is decided during the render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the listeners doesn't work once they are stored in the array. I've tried to inline the call to `getMOCField` in the `render` function and it works. Here is what I've changed to get it work:

```
class MOC extends Component {
  // ...

  addMOCField(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { mocFields } = this.state;

    // We only keep inside the state an array of number
    // each one of them represent a section of fields.
    const lastFieldId = mocFields[mocFields.length - 1] || 0;
    const nextFieldId = lastFieldId + 1;

    this.setState({
      mocFields: mocFields.concat(nextFieldId),
    });
  }

  removeMOCField(key, event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      mocFields: prevState.mocFields.filter(field => field !== key)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { mocFields } = this.state;
    const mocButton = this.getAddMOCButton();
    const toRender =
      mocFields.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="w-100 p-2 gray-background br-25">
          {/* {mocFields.map((f, index) => (
                <div key={index}>{f}</div>
              ))} */}
          {mocFields.map(fieldIndex => (
            <div key={fieldIndex}>{this.getMOCField(fieldIndex)}</div>
          ))}
          {this.getMOCFieldFooter()}
        </div>
      ) : (
        mocButton
      );

    return toRender;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in the context of my current code? What does `fields` point to in `getFieldValue`? There are 2 fields that get rendered on each call to  `addMOCField`

Comment: I've updated my answer: it's not mandatory to store the fields on the form. I've got now an implementation much closer to what you already have. I've only inlined the call `getMOCField` inside the `render` function. It does the trick.

Comment: It works fine. Also, what would be the correct way to remove the field? In the method `removeMOCField`, I have splice with the correct index but it always removes the last field. Any idea?

Comment: Yes it's because we use the length of the array to compute the field index. You can rather take the last element of the array and add one to it. You then have a value that is unique. Note that the `form` might contain now non contiguous identifier e.g. `recovery_percentage[1]`, `recovery_percentage[3]`. I've updated to reflect those changes.